# cx_Oracle: "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: mysql, cx-oracle

I'm trying to pass an UPDATE query to a `MariaDB` table via `cx_oracle`. (Python3)

And I keep getting "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting".

Say, this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `temp` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `file_logging` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `file_report` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `submission_subfolder` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `status` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

And this is the `Python` code I'm trying to run:

```
values = ['logfile', 'report_file', 'subfolder', 'FAILED']
query = "UPDATE temp SET file_logging=:1, file_report=:2, submission_subfolder=:3, status=:4 where id = 1"

cursor.execute(query, values)
cursor.commit()
```

I have defined 4 positions for positional bindings, and am passing a list with 4 values.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update your question and describe what you've installed i.e. the 'plumbing' that you are using to connect the cx_Oracle API (that uses Oracle's proprietary network protocol) to MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the pointer by @christopher-jones, I figured the problem out. (I originally thought the problem was the query, so I didn't dive into this before posting the question.)

I was using an (inhouse-written) middleware library that I thought was using `cx_Oracle` for all database handling, but for the `MariaDB` case it was using `pymysql` instead (which makes sense, of course).

And apparently, `pymysql` doesn't do positional binding the way `cx_Oracle` does but uses %s placeholders instead.

So I changed the query to:

```
query = "UPDATE temp SET file_logging=%s, file_report=%s, submission_subfolder=%s, status=%s where id = 1"
```

and now it's working.